# How to use SessionFailRetryLoop with CuratorFramework?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using [`CuratorFramework`](http://curator.apache.org/curator-framework/index.html) to talk to our Zookeeper cluster. I want the semantics provided by [`SessionFailRetryLoop`](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/SessionFailRetryLoop.html) but looks like `CuratorFramework` uses [`RetryLoop`](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/RetryLoop.html) Is there a way to tell `CuratorFramework` to use `SessionFailRetryLoop`? Or should I use [`CuratorZookeeperClient`](http://curator.apache.org/curator-client/index.html) instead of `CuratorFramework`?